Is having negative voltages on a MOSFET gate a good idea?
What is the purpose of C21 and D7 in the below circuit?
C21 is shown in the link provided to be an internal cap. However what effect does it have also placing a cap externally to the fet between the gate and the source?
Also is it a good idea to have negative voltages supplied to the gate?
D7 will clamp the gate voltage to 18V (so anything above 18V will be clamped) and will act as a forward-biased diode during the negative part of the pulse. Therefore R37 and R36 will form a potential divider.
This circuit is intended to drive a speaker.
The initial circuit was taken from here, page 3. This is basically a push-pull circuit to drive a speaker, however, I wanted to know how the circuit would behave if I applied a negative voltage as well.


If this was supposed to be a push-pull circuit, something went wrong... it's only push-push!

@TimWilliams can you elaborate?

Consider current through T2, Q3 or Q4 can only source current from +24V into either end of it, while only R36, R39 (very large resistance) or R37/R38 (via D7/D9) into the gate driver -- but if 180 ohms is enough drive for the load, why not power it directly from the 63Vpp instead?

Erm, while only ... can sink current out of T2. But yeah.

You ask "is it a good idea". It's not harmful to the MOSFET if you stay within the Vgs rating under all conditions.
It does charge the gate-source capacitance for no good reason I can think of, so the next time it turns on there will be more of a delay all things being equal. Usually that's considered a disadvantage. It's not as bad as when the MOSFET is actually switching, of course, because the G-D (gate-drain, but other interpretations are possible) capacitance has no effect.
BTW, Tim's right, that circuit cannot drive the transformer with anything but the most feeble of current since the only path to ground is through the 10kΩ resistors. You need something like a full H-bridge to drive a winding like that hard. Or a grounded centre-tap.

Given the voltages shown, is this within the safe range?

The data sheet I found for the IRF3205 says +/-20V, so if that is the correct data sheet, yes.

Not sure where you got that circuit (it’s not in the doc you linked), but as it is it’s a non-starter. 10k pull down isn’t going to do it, you need an h-bridge to drive the transformer like that. Each high-side FET needs a low-side complement to pull down.
You’ll notice that the gate positive input voltage is above that of the FET drain. This is to make it turn on fully. On the other hand, its pull-down complement that should be there doesn’t need any gate voltage lower than the negative rail. Maybe there’s supposed to be a pull-down FET to -24V to achieve a 48V swing?
The Zener’s purpose is to constrain the gate-source voltage to between -0.6V and +18V. We get the +18V keeping Vgs within the positive limit, but why the -0.6V? Likely to reduce the charge needed to turn on the FET, and thus speeding up turn-on time.
The capacitor isn’t a standalone component, and shouldn’t be in your design. It’s representing the Cgs of the circuit including parasitics and the FET gate capacitance. Look more closely at the app note you linked.
At any rate, since your voltages are kind of high you should consider using a purpose-built FET driver IC, like this one: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc7065.html. This will drive a half-bridge; you'd need two for a full bridge.

I'll tackle the first part.
What is the purpose of C21...
The Cgs and Cdg aren't capacitors the application note is suggesting that you put into your circuit.  The application note is acknowledging that there is going to be some inherent capacitance in your circuit due to adjacent traces or components.  Or, you know, maybe you do have capacitors between the gate and drain or gate and source for reasons.  The Cgs and Cdg are going to influence how much of a voltage spike you are going to see.
From the application note:

If we assume that the impedance, Z, of the drive source is high, then
any positive-going change of voltage applied across the  drain and
source terminals (caused, for example, by the switching  of another
device in the circuit) will be reflected as a  positive-going voltage
transient across the source and the drain terminals, in the
approximate ratio of:
$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{C_\mathrm{gs}}{C_\mathrm{ds}}}$$

...and D7 in the below circuit
From the application note:

Notice that a voltage clamp (a conventional zener diode is suitable
for this purpose) to prevent the gate-source voltage rating from being
exceeded will not prevent the dv/dt induced turn-on, as the gate will
not reach the zener voltage.

Their point here is that tossing in a zener doesn't actually solve the problem and may make things worse:

In many instances the zener is responsible for generating oscillations
in the gate circuit, particularly when a significant amount of stray
inductance is present.

